# How to measure time in hour and minutes

Tags: python

I am trying to train a `neural network`. One training loop takes several hours for completion. I have to run this training loop 100 times. I want to measure the time for each training loop. `time.time()` function gives it in seconds. But I want to measure this in `hours:minuts:sec`

```
for i in range(30000):
    batch = train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
    optimizer.run(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob:0.5})
```

Comment: You may want to check the `datetime` package. Difference between two `datetime.datetime` object will be an `datetime.timedelta` object which can be expressed in hours, minutes, seconds easily.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
import time
for i in range(30000):
    start = time.time()
    batch = train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
    optimizer.run(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob:0.5})
    print('Training took {}'.format(datetime.timedelta(seconds = time.time()-start)))
```

Comment: But why you have specified seconds?whereas I need time in hours,min and seconds. By specifying seconds I will only get time in seconds

Comment: The final print out will contain the hour and minute information, as the string comes from `timedelta`.